# Tighten toilet seat with nut in tough spot

Tags: toilet

I'm trying to tighten a Pressalit toilet seat on a Villeroy & Boch toilet. Unfortunately on that toilet the bolts are inside the toilet base and tough to reach. The Pressalit website shows a special tool they use to tighten the bolt which I no longer have.

[image: Hinge & tool diagram]

Any alternatives to that tool?

Here is a view of the tight spot:

[image: Rear of toilet]

[image: View of nut to tighten]

Comment: A crescent wrench or a combination wrench of the correct size should fit over the nut to provide a few degrees of turn. Ratchet wrenches may make the job easier.

Comment: Been trying an open-faced 9/16 with little luck, feels like there is a little play in the bolt and getting any leverage on it has been tough. Picture makes space look bigger than it is. Socket wrench was my first choice but was too big as I needed the deep socket to go over the extended bolt.

Comment: A [ratchet wrench set like this](https://www.google.com/search?q=husky+ratchet+wrench+set&oq=husky+ratchet&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l3.9830j0j7&client=ms-android-verizon&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) if these fit they usually will only require a few degrees (5-10) to tighten where a open end wrench takes about 35 degrees.

Comment: @EdBeal thanks. Heading out right now and will grab a set. Hoping it is indeed 9/16 and not metric so I don't have to purchase both sets.

Comment: You can always shorten the overlong bolt before inserting it from above, that will make the nut accessible to a normal length socket.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Unfortunately it's already in place so can't cut anything until I get it loose (seat was there from previous owner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is how I solved this issue.

I made a tool similar to the one shown in the hinge & tool diagram link above by wrapping a 1/2" socket with electrical tape, then securing a conduit bracket around the taped socket with more tape. This allowed me to use the portion of the conduit bracket that is screwed into the wall for leverage with my thumb to turn the nut.

Now the nut was still frozen so I used a product called PB Blaster liberally on it and after letting it sit for an hour the handmade tool above was able to break the nut loose.

Thanks everyone for your responses.

Comment: Glad you got it solved. Be sure to accept your answer to resolve the question.